# How can I check if a word has parentheses using regular expression

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to separate the words that has "[]" brackets around them, for example this line

"I hate [running] and [sweating]" how can i use regular expression just to check if a word is wrapped around "running" or "sweating" or any word.

I tried this. but it didn't work.

```
if(data.word === /[ ]/){}
```

Comment: /[\\[\\]]/.test(data.word)

Comment: `'I hate [running] and [sweating]'.match(/\[(\w+)\]/g)`

Comment: You may want to read about regexp and how to use them: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: do you want those words with or without brackets?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the expression needed :

```
/\[([^\[\]]+)\]/
```

so going by your example we would apply it as the following:

`"I hate [running] and [sweating]".match(/\[([^\[\]]+)\]/g)` 
which will result in the words with the braces , same could be applied on a single word , and we could check whether it match or not to determine if it is surrounded by square brackets

Answer (score -1):

The regular expression you need to test your example string and output all words enclosed by square brackets would be `/\[([\w]+)\]/g`

The `[\w]+` part selects all words comprised of alphanumeric characters. Including `\[` and `\]` explicitly matches the square brackets around those words.  The parentheses `(` and `)` enclose the pattern that describes which parts should be returned.

I can highly recommend [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) as a handy playground for trying our regular expressions; it's the first place I went when writing the regular expression above to check for accuracy.

An example of how to implement this can be seen [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).